# Binding checkbox events and buttons in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've written a basic "to-do list" application in pure JavaScript using the DOM API, based on a course over at Treehouse. The user should be able to add a task to an unordered list, edit the name of that task, check it off as being completed (or uncheck it as incomplete), or delete it altogether.

The pure JavaScript version works as it should; I'm trying to become more familiar with jQuery by using it to re-write this app, but I'm looking for help binding the checkboxes and other buttons to their respective functionalities.

JavaScript version - http://codepen.io/Llanyewe7/pen/bedjXv

jQuery version - http://codepen.io/Llanyewe7/pen/MewBNL

So far, only the "Add" button governed by the `addTask()` function is working as it should; my checkboxes, along with the "Edit" and "Delete" buttons, do not seem to work. The Developer Tools and JavaScript Console in Chrome do not identify any code errors; how can I effectively bind events to their "back-end" functions in jQuery to solve my problem?

Comment: Please post code examples here too. Links can go stale and then this question is no longer interesting to people finding it when searching for binding

Comment: Have a look at `jquery.ajax()` documentation

Comment: It is not clear from your code examples what your problems are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any code that binds the checkbox, edit and delete events to the new added item in list. May be try doing this:

```
var createNewTaskItem = function() {

    var newTask = $taskInput.val();

    var $listItem = $("<li></li>");
    var $checkBox = $("<input></input>").attr("type", "checkbox");
    var $label = $("<label></label>").text(newTask);
    var $editInput = $("<input></input>").attr("type", "text");
    var $editButton = $("<button></button>").text("Edit").addClass("edit");
    var $deleteButton = $("<button></button>").text("Delete").addClass("delete");


    var $newTaskItem = $listItem.append($checkBox).append($label).append($editInput).append($editButton).append($deleteButton);

    //BIND THE EVENTS TO THE NEW TASK ITEM HERE
    bindTaskEvents($newTaskItem, taskCompleted);

    return $newTaskItem;

};
```

See the new added line would bind the events to your new list item. I tested it, checkbox (checked event only), edit event and delete event are getting fired correctly. There seems to be some problem with the checkbox uncheck event. But I guess you can figure it out from there.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Thank you, @koder23! I called the `bindTaskEvents()` function within the `createNewTaskItem()` function, passing both my checkbox events as arguments. EDIT: `bindTaskEvents(newTaskItem, taskCompleted, taskIncomplete);` and now both the checked- and unchecked-box functionality is there. The reason it wasn't working before is because I had updated a variable name at some stage, and I didn't change it everywhere in my code. Thank you again -- the checkbox events work, I deleted the `$.each()` loops at the bottom, and I can continue to work on this further. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Mark the question as answered. It would help others :)